# SQL Server 2008 R2 Filestream support

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2, is setup for filestream support.

`sp_configure` however though indicate it is configured for level 2 support but not run (even after full server restart), what could be wrong?

This is confirmed as when I run

```
alter database edi 
add filegroup filestreamfilegroup
contains filestream;
```

I get

> Msg 5591, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable it on the server level over SQL Server Configuration Manager as well. Please see: http://www.ceservices.com/adding-filestream-existing-table-database-sql-2008-r2

Once you do that, it will work just fine.